# SharePoint 2013 Visual Studio Solution - Adding / Importing site pages into an existing solution

Tags: 2013, custom, solution-deployment, sitepages

I have an existing Visual Studio solution containing web parts etc.

I want to add a set of site pages to the solution, that will be deployed to the 'SitePages' folder of a site collection, when the solution is deployed.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This link helped me with this back when I tried this with SharePoint 2013 (similar to how it's done in SP2010):
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2010/06/28/creating-a-sharepoint-site-page-with-code-behind-using-visual-studio-2010.aspx

Steps:

1. add VS 2012 project
2. add module 
   [image]
3. add aspx to module (like in link above), you can copy page content from SharePoint designer after creating a site page there
4. edit Elements.xml (in module) like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="SitePagesModule" Url="SitePages">
    <File Path="SitePagesModule\SitePages\page1.aspx" Url="SitePagesModule/page1.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" />
    <File Path="SitePagesModule\SitePages\page2.aspx" Url="SitePagesModule/page2.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" />
  </Module>
</Elements>
```